# Passport facebook strategy throw Data must be string using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-facebook

I'm using `Node.js` and `passport facebook strategy` to log client in app.

I followed the passport docs but still have an error: **Data must be a string or a buffer**.

Strategy redirects to facebook page very well, but after test accepts app's conditions and it redirects to homepage, the app throw this error:

`StatusCodeError: 500 - {"error":"Data must be a string or a buffer"}`

This is my code from `auth.js` where strategy is written. I'm using `jsonwebtoken` module to sign user id.

```
exports.facebookStrategy = new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: config.auth.facebook.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.auth.facebook.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: config.auth.facebook.callbackURL,
    profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'email']
}, function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    var userProfile = {
        username: profile._json.id,
        name: profile._json.name,
        email: profile._json.email,
        facebook: true
    }
    findOrCreate(userProfile, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        // use token lib to sign id
        jwt.sign({ userId: user.username }, config.secret, {}, (e, token) => {
            if (e) {
                return done(e);
            }
            user.token = token;
            return done(null, user);
        })
    });

    function findOrCreate (user, callback) {
        client.getUser(user.username, (err, usr) => {
            if (err) {
                return client.saveUser(user, callback);
            }
            callback(null, usr);
        })
    }
});
```

Using a `console.log` I figured out that error comes from this code of block:

```
...
findOrCreate(userProfile, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.message); // it returns 500 - {"error":"Data must be a string or a buffer"}
        return done(err);
    }
```

I tried to change `profile._json` to `profile._raw`. However all values are `undefined`.

I'm using Node 6.10.0 version. and `passport: "^0.3.2"`, `"passport-facebook": "^2.1.1"`.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

This error ocurr when function to create password encrypted the parameter is null. By example:

const crypto = require('crypto')

let shasum = crypto.createHash('sha256')
shasum.update(password) // password is null

This authentication method is not require password you must code a conditional to prevent the encryption.